# Sharepoint Online - Read Only User - PnP Modern Search - Unable to get search results

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, user-permissions, sharepoint-search, pnp-js

PnP Modern Search Version 3.18

When new user gets created in Office 365 and placed into SharePoint Site's " Visitor" group with only the View Only or Read only access.

Search results in the PnP Modern Search results do not show up for that user. Users that have Edit functionality have no issues with the web parts.

Reindexing the site does nothing to fix this.

To Reproduce:

*Create user with no licence in Office 365 admin
*Add user into SharePoint " Visitor" with Read only permissions
*Go To site and search using the pnp modern search box
*Search results do not show up anything
*If user gets placed into editor permissions, search results show up.

Thank you!
I appreciate the help!

Comment: What do users with Read access see? Edit access is not required to see results with the PnP Search, but no license at all can be a factor.

Comment: They see the whole site, they can read any document and they have access to any pages, web part on the pages, and lists. Hence the search should work without issues. But it seems that the search index does not populate and does not show any results for those users. The license seems to be if you want to allow users to have office suite, exchange mail, teams, onedrive functionalities but regular user just visiting a sharepoint site doesn't need a license just access (which is the read only access) but search is just not showing results.

Answer (score 1):

Unlicensed users will only have access to content that has been shared with them. The inner workings of the PnP Search probably require more permissions than unlicensed users have. It's not just that they may be able to access the documents, but they would also need at least Read access to the web parts and code bits that are used to present the results. An unlicensed user has no access to that.